# Is there a way to do rolling percentage in pandas with three columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm looking for a method to perform rolling percantage in a Pandas DataFrame with three columns. For each row in my df, I want to calculate the difference between the last three rows and the triple-wise rows in that column and then do this for each column. With the output, I want to sum the average of each row. Below, I will try to show you what I mean and what I have tried. However, as you will be able to tell, my knowledge is limited and I'm looking for a faster and more efficent way to produce likwise output as below but for each row in a larger DataFrame...

I'm greatful for any feedback!

My test dataset looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,2,4,5,6,3,4],[1,3,4,6,7,2,3,4],[1,2,2,4,12,9,8,4]]).T
print(df1)
   0  1   2
0  1  1   1
1  3  3   2
2  2  4   2
3  4  6   4
4  5  7  12
5  6  2   9
6  3  3   8
7  4  4   4
```

If I was to do this "manually" it would start with this:

```
pctChange = pd.DataFrame([df1.First.pct_change(periods=3),df1.Second.pct_change(periods=3),df1.Third.pct_change(periods=3)]).T

print(pctChange)
          First    Second     Third
    0       NaN       NaN       NaN
    1       NaN       NaN       NaN
    2       NaN       NaN       NaN
    3  3.000000  5.000000  3.000000
    4  0.666667  1.333333  5.000000
    5  2.000000 -0.500000  3.500000
    6 -0.250000 -0.500000  1.000000
    7 -0.200000 -0.428571 -0.666667
```

Then taking the average of each row.

```
ave = pctChange.mean(axis=1)
print(ave)

0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3    3.666667
4    2.333333
5    1.666667
6    0.083333
7   -0.431746
```

Finally, sum the latest three rows

```
    SumOfLastThree = ave.iloc[-3:].sum()
    print(SumOfLastThree)
#desired output
    1.3182539682539682
```

Comment: Have a look into the `.rolling()` function.  [Pandas docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).  And also the `.diff()` function.  [Docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

Comment: Thanks @S3DEV, I will have another look and try to figure out how to accomplish this!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try this to get your 3 day moving average:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,2,4,5,6,3,4],[1,3,4,6,7,2,3,4],[1,2,2,4,12,9,8,4]]).T
df1.columns = ['First','Second','Third']
#3 day rolling average of value
df1['PctChange1']=pd.to_numeric(df1.First.rolling(3,min_periods=3).mean().fillna(''))
```

I did pd.to_numeric because it was returning an object. To change the size of the moving average, you would change the first parameter `.rolling()`. If you want to still have a rolling average for the first couple rows, you can change it `min_periods=1` - that should allow you to add that moving average as a new column in your frame.
Then your rolling sum would be:

```
df1['RollingSum'] = pd.to_numeric(df1.PctChange1.rolling(3,min_periods=3).sum().fillna(''))
```

Add it all up:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3,2,4,5,6,3,4],[1,3,4,6,7,2,3,4],[1,2,2,4,12,9,8,4]]).T
df1.columns = ['First','Second','Third']
#3 day rolling average of value
df1['PctChange1']=pd.to_numeric(df1.First.rolling(3,min_periods=3).mean().fillna(''))
#sum of last three rolling averages
df1['RollingSum'] = pd.to_numeric(df1.PctChange1.rolling(3,min_periods=3).sum().fillna(''))
df1
```

Let me know if that works!